# Missing some tiles in dev when apply mbtiles in tileserver-gl Maptiler

Tags: mbtiles, tile-server, maptiler, tileserver-gl

Left side is the local host by using the command

```
tileserver-gl-light -b 0.0.0.0 -p 8009 --mbtiles something16.mbtiles
```

http://localhost:8009/data/openmaptiles/#18/3.95245/101.03776,
then right side is the dev

The mbtiles looks good (left hand side), but when I applied to the dev (right hand side), there is a missing part. Does the `tileserver-gl-light` got the limit area to show up?

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Tileserver GL has been replaced by MapTiler Server
and it is no longer supported by MapTiler...

Answer (score 0):

Two things you can check:

- the bounds in the config.py for your style. if the tile does not fit the bounds it won't show

  "styles": {
  "your_style": {
  "style": "/styles/your_style.json",
  "tilejson": {
  "type": "overlay",
  "bounds": [6.7499552751, 36.619987291, 18.4802470232, 47.1153931748]
  }
  },
- If you have used geometric simplifications with tools like tippecanoe, disable them and regenerate the mbtiles served bu the tileserver